# Two Week Timetable in PHP

Tags: php, json

So I'm making an interactive timetable which is for a school with a two week timetable however I'm having problems working out whether we are currently week 1 or two. This is complicated as if you end a half term on week 2 it will ignore the week schools out and continue on week 1. I can't seem to for the life of me work out a way to achieve this in PHP. I have the school year defined in Jason:

```
[
{
    "day": {
        "1": {
            "type": "lesson",
            "info": "1",
            "start": "09:00",
            "end": "10:00"
        },
        "2": {
            "type": "lesson",
            "info": "2",
            "start": "10:00",
            "end": "11:00"
        },
        "3": {
            "type": "break",
            "info": "break",
            "start": "11:00",
            "end": "11:20"
        },
        "4": {
            "type": "lesson",
            "info": "3",
            "start": "11:20",
            "end": "12:20"
        },
        "5": {
            "type": "lesson",
            "info": "4",
            "start": "13:20",
            "end": "14:10"
        },
        "6": {
            "type": "lunch",
            "info": "lunch",
            "start": "12:20",
            "end": "13:20"
        },
        "7": {
            "type": "lesson",
            "info": "5",
            "start": "14:10",
            "end": "15:10"
        }
    },
    "terms": {
        "1": {
            "name": "auturm",
            "1": {
                "start": "07-09-2015",
                "end": "23-10-2015"
            },
            "2": {
                "start": "03-11-2015",
                "end": "18-12-2015"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "spring",
            "1": {
                "start": "04-01-2016",
                "end": "12-02-2016"
            },
            "2": {
                "start": "22-02-2016",
                "end": "01-04-2016"
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "summer",
            "1": {
                "start": "19-04-2016",
                "end": "27-05-2016"
            },
            "2": {
                "start": "06-06-2016",
                "end": "20-07-2016"
            }
        }
    },
    "breaks": [ 
        "02-09-2015",
        "02-09-2015",
        "18-04-2016",
        "21-07-2016",
        "22-07-2016",
        "25-07-2016",
        "31-08-2015",
        "25-03-2016",
        "28-03-2016",
        "02-05-2016"
    ]
}
```

And a example timetable:

```
[
{
    "week": {
        "1": {
            "1": {
                "name": "monday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "CA",
                    "room": "S1"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "KL",
                    "room": "A14"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "History",
                    "teacher": "SH",
                    "room": "C18"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "History",
                    "teacher": "SH",
                    "room": "C18"
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "tuesday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Religious Education",
                    "teacher": "AB",
                    "room": "C13"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "DT",
                    "room": "A13"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "Physical Education",
                    "teacher": "DV",
                    "room": "Gym"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "AB",
                    "room": "S4"
                }
            },
            "3": {
                "name": "wednesday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Geography",
                    "teacher": "RM",
                    "room": "C12"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Computer Science",
                    "teacher": "SR",
                    "room": "S7"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Product Design",
                    "teacher": "SOM",
                    "room": "D6"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "Product Design",
                    "teacher": "SOM",
                    "room": "D6"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "KL",
                    "room": "A14"
                }
            },
            "4": {
                "name": "wednesday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Geography",
                    "teacher": "RB",
                    "room": "C4"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Geography",
                    "teacher": "RB",
                    "room": "C4"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Computer Science",
                    "teacher": "SR",
                    "room": "C7"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "History",
                    "teacher": "SH",
                    "room": "C18"
                }
            },
            "5": {
                "name": "friday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "DT",
                    "room": "A13"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "SE",
                    "room": "S7"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "CA",
                    "room": "S1"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "Physical Education",
                    "teacher": "DV",
                    "room": "Gym"
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "1": {
                "name": "monday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "AB",
                    "room": "S4"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "CA",
                    "room": "S1"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "DT",
                    "room": "A13"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "tuesday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "SE",
                    "room": "S7"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Product Design",
                    "teacher": "SOM",
                    "room": "D6"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "AB",
                    "room": "S4"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "Physical Education",
                    "teacher": "DV",
                    "room": "Gym"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "KL",
                    "room": "C3"
                }
            },
            "3": {
                "name": "wednesday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Computer Science",
                    "teacher": "SR",
                    "room": "C7"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Computer Science",
                    "teacher": "SR",
                    "room": "S7"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Product Design",
                    "teacher": "SOM",
                    "room": "D6"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "Product Design",
                    "teacher": "SOM",
                    "room": "D6"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                }
            },
            "4": {
                "name": "Thursday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Geography",
                    "teacher": "RM",
                    "room": "C12"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Geography",
                    "teacher": "RB",
                    "room": "C4"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "History",
                    "teacher": "SH",
                    "room": "C18"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "History",
                    "teacher": "SH",
                    "room": "C18"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "SE",
                    "room": "S7"
                }
            },
            "5": {
                "name": "friday",
                "1": {
                    "subject": "English",
                    "teacher": "GF",
                    "room": "E1"
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Maths",
                    "teacher": "KL",
                    "room": "C3"
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Science",
                    "teacher": "CA",
                    "room": "S1"
                },
                "4": {
                    "subject": "Computer Science",
                    "teacher": "SR",
                    "room": "C7"
                },
                "5": {
                    "subject": "Physical Education",
                    "teacher": "DV",
                    "room": "Gym"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I have no problems working out what the current lesson is per day and within a week just what the week is.

EDIT: To clarity I'm trying to get a function that will return the current week (1/2) for example today (this week) should return 1

Comment: I suggest you to use 11-17 for week1 and 21-27 for week2. or a1-a7/b1-b7 something like that. Multidigit/multi character variable/name.

Comment: Sorry I was wanting is to say look its the 24th Sep today so its week 1 and then next week go look its week 2 now

Comment: I didn't understand. Edit your question and give some example in it.